# How to go back to a particular page using history.back sort of functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have two pages say A and B. I landed to page B from A.
Now on clicking back button, in page B. I want to go to page A.

Right now I am using windows.location.href="URL of A page";
Basially it redirecting to Page A (i.e Loading Page A again)

Reloading / Redirecting takes enough time, Windows.history.back() is superbly fast but i am performing many activities on Page B so i can't use this.

So any solution to this problem.

Comment: I think you better focus on improving page A. history.back implementation is on browser to use cache or hit server. It's possible that some browser uses caches and it's fast and some not so it would be equally slow as window.location.href. If cached page is a solution for you, then use html 5 offline cache manifest.

Comment: You can use `window.history.go(-3);` to go back 3 pages. Maybe this will be helpful in your case

Comment: As in the above problem i have mentioned that i am performing n no. of activities on Page B so window.history.go(-3); will not redirect me to Page A it will just go back -3 (i.e some activity perform on Page B )

Comment: If you have angular implemented, then uirouter might be helpful here. But probably not worth adding angular just for this. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router

Comment: Can you put the url in a session variable? Is this a general situation that you want to do on many different pages, or is this page-specific just two pages on your site?

Comment: yes i can save in session or in cookie.. but the issue still remains of redirecting to that stored page which will take hell lot of time in loading